# Three monitors, clicks on right monitor triggers on left monitor (and vice versa)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

I just installed Ubuntu 19 alongside Windows 10 on my PC again. I have three monitors. One 16:9 in the middle and 16:10 on the left and right . When I put all of them in the right order (1 on the left, 2 in the middle, 3 on the right; which should be correct according to device names shown) It displays a 1 on the right monitor and a 3 on the left though (those icons in the top left) If I move my cursor to the right, the cursor is on the right screen, but all clicks trigger on the left screen. If my cursor is on the left screen, clicks trigger on the right screen. Flipping the two around in the Settings makes clicks trigger on the correct monitor, but moving my cursor to the left, makes it appear on the right obviously. How can I fix this? I had it working on a previous Ubuntu 19 Installation from the same ISO.
So tl/dr: Monitors seem to be aligned the right way in System Settings however they are flipped (all contents) besides the mouse.

Comment: What model Nvidia? What version Nvidia driver?

Comment: The Graphics Card is a RTX 2070. I currently don't have any drivers installed, because every time I try to install the Drivers Ubuntu recommends, booting gets stuck and starting the Desktop or something along the lines of that

Comment: Tell me your make/model #/service tag # of your computer, and show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: The command you told me outputs 3803. However I don't really understand what you mean with the first question. Like pre-built Computer Brand? If yes, there isn't any. Because the computer is custom built (well it was build by a human from a PC Building Company, but it's no retail computer)

Comment: With custom build computers, then I'd need the make/model # of the main motherboard. If nothing else, you'll see it painted on the board itself... or you might see it in the BIOS.

Comment: Another way to get the info... `sudo dmidecode -s system-manufacturer` and `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` and `sudo dmidecode -s system-version`

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I tried a few things more things and eventually just gave up. Tried Elementary OS. Same Issue. Deepin had a different Issue. I think I'm just gonna stay with Windows until Linux works better with Nvidia Drivers.

Comment: Did you install Nvidia 440.44? Did you check the BIOS version? Use the 4 commands I gave earlier.

Comment: I tried multiple Drivers (both via official installers and apt) nothing worked. I don't have Ubuntu installed atm anymore though

Comment: If you didn't check the BIOS, then you gave up too early. You could still do it by entering the BIOS and it should give you the manufacturer and version there.

Comment: Since I currently dont have Ubuntu installed anymore, I ran those commands in Elementary where I also have this issue (+wrong resolution even though settings are right), but the output should probably be the same, since it's based on Ubuntu.
`sudo dmidecode -s system-manufacturer` outputs "System manufacteurer"
`sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` outputs "System Product Name" and `sudo dmidecode -s system-version` outputs "System Version". I don't think this is really the output this should give, right?
(Oh I overlooked the command `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` which outputs: "3803")

Comment: The manufacturer didn't fill this stuff out. Let's see if `sudo dmidecode -t 1` or `sudo dmidecode -t 2` gives us any more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Nvidia drivers.

However, there have been some problems with these drivers, and the 5.3 kernel found in Ubuntu 19.xx.

The drivers found in `Software & Updates` are probably older Nvidia drivers.

Go to https://www.geforce.com/drivers and download/install version 440.44, (from Dec 11, 2019) of these drivers.

Comment: A few things
1) The installer tells me I should install it via apt (should I do it?)
2) If I still select continue, it tells me I have to disable noveau (or something like that) first
3) If I then select it should write some files to disable noveau, it says it has written files but then the installer errors out

Comment: Now only one monitor is working. Looks like my Installation is pretty broken. Probably gonna reinstall

Comment: @OfficialCRUGG no need to reinstall yet. What's the specific error messages that you see? If you look in `Software & Updates` Additional Drivers you'll see noveau and the older Nvidia drivers, and possibly a choice to disable. If you have to, choose one of the Nvidia drivers there, and then you can install the newer Nvidia driver after that with `sudo apt-get install nvidia_blah_blah.deb`